# Jquery load into DIV

Tags: jquery, html, load

I have the following problem:

I have in the first HTML:
(index.html)

```
<html>  
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#options").load('options.html');
     });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="options"></div>
  <div id="containers"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I load the second page (options.html) into div 'options'

and in the second HTML:
(options.html)

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#options").load('options.html');
     });
   </script>
<body>
<div id="options">
    <a href="anypage.html">any page</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

is working! but I would like to load the link "any page" of page 'options.html' in the div 'containers' of page 'index.html'.

how do I do that?

Comment: you can't, at least not with your current html. try putting the link in its own file, then load that into `containers`. or, put the `containers` div in options.html.

Comment: so you want the anchor element? or the contents of the actual 'anypage.html' ?

Answer (score 1):

You just Need to do :-

```
 $("#containers").load('options.html #options');
```

[from jquery docs:-](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed.

Comment: I think he wants it in the `#containers` div `but I would like to load the link "any page" of page 'options.html' in the div 'containers' of page 'index.html'.`